# Regex for the first 3 digits in a 6 digit number

Tags: regex, filter

I have items in a cms which have a 6-digit number.
The user can filter these item, via a input field,
by start typing a number.

```
const list = document.querySelector('#filter-wrap');

const searchBar = document.forms['search-kelim'].querySelector('input');
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  const term = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  const kelims = list.getElementsByClassName('filter-item');
  Array.from(kelims).forEach(function(kelim){
    let number = kelim.firstElementChild.textContent;
    if(number.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1 ){
      console.log("Valid");
    } else {
      console.log("Invalid");
    }
  });
});
```

This is working, but it filters no matter where the digit
is occurring within the 6-digit number.

Aim is, it should only filter the first 3 starting digits, already starting with the first digit.
Meaning, if the user types 2, only the items starting with 2 are shown,
if the user then types 1, only the items starting with 21 are shown.
(the same for the third digit, typing 214 matches only the items starting with 214)

instead of `indexof` i tried with regex, but cannot get it to work:

```
var re = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$");
    if (re.test(term)) {
        console.log("Valid");
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid");
    }
```

also tried these regex:

```
var re = new RegExp("^[0-9]");
var re = new RegExp("^\d{3}[0-9]");
var re = new RegExp("/[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}/");
```

i also tried with `match` but also no luck, (different syntax?)

UPDATE:
here are two codepens for better understanding:
Filter with indexof, working but for first 3 digits.
https://codepen.io/hhentschel/pen/LYNWKeK

Filter with Regex, i tried all different answers, which came up so far.
https://codepen.io/hhentschel/pen/yLOMmbw

Comment: Are you sure you are testing against a regex the current text box value as a whole and not the last char typed?

Comment: `^\d{3}` matches the first three digits no matter how many there are. To force just finding 3 of 6 digit do `^(\d{3})\d{3}$`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: what code are you referring to? until now it alway goes to the invalid console.log

Comment: @MarkusZeller: unfortunatly it does not work. i updated my question with two codepens, maybe this helps.

Comment: When the string is beginning which is a newline instead of a decimal, then `^` will not work, of course. But you could exclude any whitespaces. `^\s*(\d{3})\d{3}\s*$` (same as trimming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `number` variables all start with a line break. You may easily check that if you add `console.log("'"+number+"': number")` in the code.

To fix the regex approach, you just need to trim the incoming strings:

```
var re = new RegExp("^"+term);
if (re.test(number.trim())) {   // <-- HERE!
  kelim.classList.add("block");
  kelim.classList.remove("hide");
} else {
  kelim.classList.add("hide");
  kelim.classList.remove("block");
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. That works. Did`nt know/checked that. Also thanks to @yannick818.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the Index is 0:

```
if(number.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) == 0){
  console.log("Valid");
} else {
  console.log("Invalid");
}
```

So you know that the term is at the beginning of the number.

But if you want to use regex, you have to build a new pattern every time:

```
var re = new RegExp("^"+term);
    if (re.test(number)) {
        console.log("Valid");
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid");
    }
```

Comment: Question is about how to do using regex, not plain programming.

Comment: Indexof i already tried, see my question. 
your regex answer unfortunatly does not work for me. I added two codepens in my question for better understanding. There i tried your regex, but no luck.

Comment: @Henrik Checking for `IndexOf(..) != -1` is wrong if you want it to check the *start*.